# Set HTML attributes on ASP.Net MVC 4 HTML Helpers?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

If I specify an HTML form element like a text field like so:

```
@Html.TextBox(m => m.UserName)
```

How can I add other standard HTML attributes to it, e.g. 'class', 'id', 'placeholder' etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [InputExtensions.TextBox Method (HtmlHelper, String, Object, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493049(v=vs.118).aspx)

Example:

```
@Html.TextBox(m => m.UserName, "<<NameOfTextBox>>", "<<Value>>", new { @class="MyClass", placeholder="placeholder" })
```

Answer (score 2):

Hai Please use Class and patchholder like below

```
@Html.TextBox(m => m.UserName, new { @placeholder = "User Name", @class = "txt" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this: `@Html.TextBox(m => m.UserName, new{@id = id, @class = yourClassName})`

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload for that

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

You must prefix class with @ bc it's a reserved keyword but it is not required by the rest

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new {@class = "btn btn-primary", placeholder="Enter text Here"})
```

Answer (score 0):

@Html.TextBox(m => m.UserName, 
    new { placeholder = "type a name..." } )

or 
[DisplayName("Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }

@model string

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { @placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName })